# Postgres text sorting: white space is lesser than end of string in json strings - bug or working as intended?

Tags: json, postgresql

If I perform this simple query

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM (
  SELECT 'abc' AS name 
  UNION ALL 
  SELECT 'abc d' AS name
) AS test 
ORDER BY name;
```

I get (as expected) the following result:

```
name
-------
 abc
 abc d
(2 rows)
```

i.e. the space character of string `abc d` is considered greater than the end of string of `abc`.

Till here everything is fine.

Next, if I try:

```sql
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT '{"name":"AbC"}'::JSON AS json
  UNION ALL
  SELECT '{"name":"aBc D"}'::JSON AS json
) AS test ORDER BY LOWER((json -> 'name')::TEXT);
```

I get:

```
      json
------------------
 {"name":"aBc D"}
 {"name":"AbC"}
(2 rows)
```

this time the space character of string `abc d` is **considered lesser than the end of string** of `abc`!

I also tried with:

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM (
  SELECT 'abc'::TEXT AS name 
  UNION ALL SELECT 'abc d'::TEXT AS name
) AS test 
ORDER BY name;
```

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM (
  SELECT 'abc' AS name 
  UNION ALL 
  SELECT 'abc d' AS name
) AS test 
ORDER BY LOWER(name);
```

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM (
  SELECT 'abc'::TEXT AS name 
  UNION ALL 
  SELECT 'abc d'::TEXT AS name
) AS test 
ORDER BY LOWER(name);
```

and all of them give the expected result.

I also tried:

```sql
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT '{"name":"abc"}'::JSON AS json
  UNION ALL
  SELECT '{"name":"abc d"}'::JSON AS json
) AS test 
ORDER BY (json -> 'name')::TEXT;
```

which considers the space character lesser than the end of string as well.

It seems that the *unexpected* behavior is originated by the conversion of a string property of a `JSON` field to a (any?) postgres string type. I tried to search in PostrgeSQL documentation for a reason of this phenomenon but I wasn't able to.

Could somebody point me the documentation speaking about this?
Or should we consider this a bug?

Comment: I think the horse is right, does it convert jsonb to text first before sorting? select pg_typeof(('{"name": "abc"}'::jsonb)->'name') is still jsonb at this stage

Comment: Yes @MâttFrëëman , it is. So now the question is: which is the right convertion function? With _right conversion function_ I mean the function which also excludes the double quotes

Comment: it uses compareJsonbContainers which calls compareJsonbScalarValue  which then compares the string - the quoted string in this case rather than the unwrapped one https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/c8e1ba736b2b9e8c98d37a5b77c4ed31baf94147/src/backend/utils/adt/jsonb_util.c#L1438 - interesting. But alas the answer is ->> or jsonb_extract_path_text if you want to compare without quotes.

Comment: Use the ->> operator instead of ->

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `->>` operator to extract the sort value as `text` directly.

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
  SELECT '{"name":"AbC"}'::JSON AS json
  UNION ALL
  SELECT '{"name":"aBc D"}'::JSON AS json
) AS test 
ORDER BY LOWER(json ->> 'name');
```

Casting a `JSON` value to `text` does something different.

---

Your attempt:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
  SELECT '{"name":"abc"}'::JSON AS json
  UNION ALL
  SELECT '{"name":"abc d"}'::JSON AS json
) AS test 
ORDER BY lower((json -> 'name')::TEXT);
```

Is equivalent to this setup:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
  SELECT '"abc"' AS name 
  UNION ALL 
  SELECT '"abc d"' AS name
) AS test 
ORDER BY name;
```

---

I don't know *why* the double quotes change the sort order though. It probably has something to do with the underlying collation. Maybe it would be possible to create an ICU collation that sorts quoted strings the same ways as unquoted strings.